# How to use Apollo Studio to explore Dgraph

Tags: dgraph, apollo-studio

I've setup a Dgraph using the docker version. I'm currently able to manipulate the schema and query the graph using Ratel (dgraphs' official tooling); but I want to be able to connect to my graph using Apollo Studio. I tried http://localhost:8080 and http://localhost:8080/graphql in the apollo studio but it can't connect. It was said somewhere in their forum that I need to setup apollo server in front of the dgraph to be able to use apollo studio. Can someone guide me on the steps needed to do so?

Comment: It might be a security issue. Did you set any whitelist in your docker config?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the docker-compose.yaml that I use:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  zero:
    image: dgraph/dgraph:latest
    volumes:
      - d:/dgraph:/dgraph
    ports:
      - 5080:5080
      - 6080:6080
    restart: on-failure
    command: dgraph zero --my=zero:5080
  alpha:
    image: dgraph/dgraph:latest
    volumes:
      - d:/dgraph:/dgraph
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9080:9080
    restart: on-failure
    command: dgraph alpha --my=alpha:7080 --zero=zero:5080 --security whitelist=0.0.0.0/0
  ratel:
    image: dgraph/ratel:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: dgraph-ratel
```

Here whitelist=0.0.0.0/0 which I wouldn't leave it like that but this is a temporary test environment for me.

And in apollo (https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer) I can use:

```
http://localhost:8080/graphql
http://localhost:8080/admin
```

Note: In my case I use local d:\DGraph for dgraph data folder.